# What are the best sources to find labelled review data sets for text classification?

Tags: data-request, nlp, classification, text

I have been searching for labelled review data sets for training for label classification. However it has been a bit surprising for me that I could find only sentiment classification data sets and nothing else.

I am not sure if am doing the search right. While I understand that the engine should be trained for our data, trying with some ready made labelled review sets would make the algo be ready faster.

Are you aware of any sources where I can obtain labelled review data sets for label classification? If a free one does not work, paid sources are also fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[User Review Datasets](https://kavita-ganesan.com/user-review-datasets/#.XuiYsUUzbDc)

These datasets below contain reviews from Rotten Tomatoes, Amazon, TripAdvisor, Yelp, Edmunds.com, and so on. Here are some of the many datasets available out there:

---

- [Consumer Reviews of Amazon Products](https://www.kaggle.com/datafiniti/consumer-reviews-of-amazon-products)

  - A list of over 34,000 reviews of Amazon products like the Kindle, Fire TV, etc
- [100K Coursera's Course Reviews Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/septa97/100k-courseras-course-reviews-dataset)

  - 100K+ Scraped Course Reviews from the Coursera Website (As of May 2017)

[More review datasets from Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/search?q=review%20datasets%20in%3Adatasets)

Comment: Thank you - OpinRank and Opinosis data sets work. I am yet to go through the complete Kaggle list.

Comment: From Kaggle I could not find any. In fact many data sets given there have labelled sentiments, but do not have topics labelled. I am specifically looking for topic label classification - I think I missed to mention that in the description.